# Regex to match a set of words that is not preceded by, within 25 characters, another set of words

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'd like to write a regex to match a set of words (offered/gave me a job.) that is not preceded by, within 25 characters, another set of words(did not, would not, etc) within the same sentence. I more or less understand how to get the group of words, but I cannot figure out why the negative lookbehind doesn't work here. Also, I need to accomplish this in only one regex, and I am using python to test these. Here are some example matches/non-matches:

```
Match:
he offered me a job
she gave me a job

Does not match:
he did not even offer me a job
she would not give me a job
he did not think about offering me a job
```

Here is my regex so far: `(?<!did not)[^\.\n]{0,25}(?:(?:offer(ed|ing|s)?|g[ai]ves?)[^\.\n\!\?]{0,25}(?:job))`

And here's a [regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/aDGUkg/3).

Comment: In PCRE, only like [this](https://regex101.com/r/9bT5zb/1)

Comment: thanks @WiktorStribiżew but I am not sure this will work for my purposes.

Comment: It will work for your purposes, unless you are not using PCRE.

Comment: If the "match strings" were "ab" and "cd", and the "does not mach" strings were "ef" and "gh", do you want to match either "ab" and "cd", provided it is not preceded by, within 25 characters, `"ef"` or `"gh"`?

Comment: Thanks for the response, Cary. I'm deleting my comment as well (and soon this too, if no longer relevant)

Comment: thank you for all the comments! @CarySwoveland Yes - that's the right idea. I want to match a group of words that are not preceded by (within 25 characters) another group of words. I apologize for the slow response, but I'm still trying to wrap my head around your answer below. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I've assumed the problem is to match the string `"ab"` or `"cd"` provided it is not preceded by less than 10 characters by the string `"ef"` or `"gh"`.

I must make an assumption about the structure of the string: if `"ef"` or `"gh"` precedes `"ab"` or `"cd"`, and the latter precedes `"ef"` or `"gh"`, the latter is not followed by `"ab"` or `"cd"`.

Here is a regular expression that could be used, provided the regex engine supports *negative lookaheads*. I've tested it with the PCRE engine.

```
(?:ef|gh).{0,9}(?:ab|cd)(?!.*(?:ab|cd))|(ab|cd)(?!.*(?:ab|cd))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ilCtxo/1/)

I have employed what has been called ["the greatest regex trick ever"](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html).

Notice that the regex has the form `X|(Y)`. If `X` is matched, capture group 1 is empty. If `X` is not matched, capture group 1 will contain the last instance in the line of the string `"ab"` or `"cd"`.

`X` is an expression which, if matched, means that there is no string `"ab"` or `"cd"` that follows a string `"cd"` or `"ef"` by at least 10 characters.

We therefore disregard what is matched and only examine capture group 1. If it's empty, the objective fails; if is nonempty the objective succeeds, the objective being to find the *last* instance of the string `"ab"` or `"cd"` that is not preceded by `"cd"` or `"ef"` or that follows the *last* preceding `"cd"` or `"ef"` by at least 10 characters.

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?:ef|gh)       # match 'ef' or 'gh'
.{0,9}          # match 0-9 characters
(?:ab|cd)       # match 'ab' or 'cd'
(?!             # begin a negative lookahead
  .*            # match 0+ characters
  (?:ab|cd)     # match 'ab' or 'cd' 
)               # end negative lookahead 
|               # or
(ab|cd)         # match 'ab' or 'cd' 
(?!.*(?:ab|cd)) # match is to not be followed later in the line by 'ab' or 'cd'
```

The *negative lookahead*, `(?!.*(?:ab|cd))`, which appears twice, ensures that the preceding match of `"ab"` or `"cd"`, if there is one, is the last instance of either string in the line.

As usual, if multi-line strings are to be matched some small changes are needed. I have written the regex to match within lines so I can demonstrate the effect of the regex for multiple strings at the linked on-line regex tester.

Comment: It looks your regex matches the 5 examples except for the last line in the DEMO.
 I'm afraid it may not be what the OP expects.

Comment: @tshionno, why would the OP expect a match of a string that contains neither `"ab"` nor `"cd"`?

Comment: I'm assuming the OP would expect a match with line 1, 4 and 5 in the DEMO examples. This is my own assumption anyway and would be better to wait for the feedback by the OP.

Comment: @tshiono, I think you may be suggesting that a match requires `"ab"` or `"cd"` to be preceded by `"ef"` or `"gh"` (aside from the amount of space between the two). I interpreted, "that is not preceded by" to be satisfied if `"ab"` or `"cd"` is not preceded `"ef"` or `"gh"` at all. As you suggest, the OP will need to clarify that.

Comment: thank you for the response. First let me correct my previous comment; I'm assuming the OP would expect `line 1, 2, 4, 5` to match. They are expressed as `partial matches` in your DEMO. Let's wait for the OP's feedback anyway. BTW let me praise your regex idea is marvelous.

Comment: @tshiono, lines 1, 2, 4 5 are the examples I found to match, as they are the ones for which capture group 1 contains a value, which is all that matters.